# Ambiguity in function definition in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am new to JS so bear with me.

What is the difference between

```
function get (attr) {
  return function (object) { return object[attr]; }
}
```

and

```
function get (attr) {
  return object[attr];
}
```

Why the first function worked but second did not? could not find a logical explanation for this.
Working Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/xf2u0ncL/

Comment: the first one return a function and second one return a object

Comment: I see no ambiguity here

Comment: @Azzi the second will return anything, string, function, number, object. Depends what that property its returning is.

Comment: There is no `object` in the second one

Answer (score 0):

In your second code, where does `object` come from?! That's the entire problem.

The first code is used like this:

```
// same as getter = function (object) { return object['foo']; }
var getter = get('foo');
var value = getter({ foo: 'bar' });
```

`get` accepts a property name and returns a function which accepts an object and returns the value. Your second function doesn't accept any object at any point, so what's it supposed to return?

Comment: Agreed that object isn't declared in second func. But how did the browser got to know that it was the object not the attribute itself in the first  function when object was passed? how did it differentiate that at first attribute was passed in get and then in inner function object was passed.

Comment: Because of scoping. The attribute passed in the first function is in the same scope of the returned function meaning the returned function has access to it.  That is a really bad way of explaining it though, this may help http://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/ Essentially the first function set a different variable which the second function has access to. the second function sets a different variable. Thats how t know which is which.

Comment: @chakra Because that's what the function says it does. `attr` passed to `get` is later used in `object[attr]`, that's pretty clear. And `object` is an argument to the function that `get` returns. You need to learn about *higher order functions* (functions which return functions) and *closures* (the mechanism by which `attr` is available later in `object[attr]`). Google for these keywords and learn, no need to clarify these things here from scratch in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got a method where your trying to return a property of an object.

Both methods above will work but expect variables in different scopes and will be executed differently.

the first method returns a second method where you pass it an object to get the property from. So

```
get('foo')({foo: 'bar'}); //returns 'bar'
```

Whereas the second works like this

```
var object = {
   foo: 'bar'
}

get('foo'); //returns 'bar';
```

the second excepts `object` to be a global variable or at least in a higher scope as it is not defined in the function it self.

the first method is passed an object to search for a property from. The first, whilst a little convoluted would be better and more easily tested than the second which expects and relies on global variables.

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b327nr74/